# Enter emp details in HTML and save to MySql database through JSP called by HTML

Tags: jsp

**emp.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="wheat">
<center>
<form action="insert.jsp" method="post">
Empno: <input type="text" name="t1"> <br><br>
Empname:<input type="text" name="t2"> <br><br>
Salary:<input type="text" name="t3"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="createEmp">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**insert.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

<%!
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;
public void jspInt(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","test");
        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into emp values(?,?,?)");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
public void jspDestroy() {
    try {
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
%>
<%
int eid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t1"));
String ename = request.getParameter("t2");
float sal = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("t3"));
ps.setInt(1, eid);
ps.setString(2, ename);
ps.setFloat(3, sal);
ps.executeUpdate();
%>
<%@ include file="emp.html" %>
```

**Error:** When I click the submit button I am receive a null pointer exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp.jspDestroy(insert_jsp.java:27)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.destroy(HttpJspBase.java:84)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.destroy(JspServletWrapper.java:321)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:131)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:253)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:258)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:205)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
>           at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

I am using MySQL 5.5, Tomcat 5 and JDK 1.5. I configured build path and added server lib and mysql connector. jar. Please throw some light on this.

Comment: Are you sure you are overriding the jspInit method? It seems you are writing a new method called jspInt

Comment: yes, you are correct.One more question . In welcome file list i have given emp.html as welcome file. but i am getting a list of files in directory .

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nothing wrong. i am getting desired result.

Comment: You have written jdbc initialization code in jspInt method which is not `jspInit()` of jsp, so how are you getting your jdbc driver and prepared statement initialized?